# PAHO-MQTT subscribe on multiple topics with wildcards

Tags: python, mqtt

I'm using `paho-mqtt 1.6.1` with `Python 3.11.3` on Windows 11.

I'm trying to subscribe on 3 topics using also wildcards.

```
topic = [('A/#/B', 1), ('A/#/C', 1), ('A/#/D', 1)]
client.subscribe(topic)
```

but I get `raise ValueError('Invalid subscription filter.')`.

However I can subscribe to single level wildcard such as

```
topic = [('A/+/B', 1), ('A/+/C', 1), ('A/+/D', 1)]
client.subscribe(topic)
```

Why am I able to subscribe to single level wildcard but not to multilevel wildcard?

Also, I am able to subscribe to subscribe to a multilevel wildcard only on a single topic such as

```
topic = topic = 'A/#'
client.subscribe(topic)
```

Comment: In the MQTT protocol the `#` wildcard is allowed at the end only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the MQTT [Spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718107)

> *4.7.1.2 Multi-level wildcard**
>
> The number sign (‘#’ U+0023) is a wildcard character that matches any number of levels within a topic. The multi-level wildcard represents the parent and any number of child levels. The multi-level wildcard character MUST be specified either on its own or following a topic level separator. **In either case it MUST be the last character specified in the Topic Filter** [MQTT-4.7.1-2]
>
> ...
>
> *Non normative comment*
>
> - “sport/#” also matches the singular “sport”, since # includes the parent level.
> - “#” is valid and will receive every Application Message
> - “sport/tennis/#” is valid
> - “sport/tennis#” is not valid
> - “sport/tennis/#/ranking” is not valid

The `#` char must always be at the end of a topic filter.